# Problem integrating WCF with Sharp architecture

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, exception, s#arp-architecture

I'm working with an application which uses wcf and sharp architecture, I'm trying to create a service to write to the database. Here is my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFacilitiesWcfService : ICloseableAndAbortable
{
    [OperationContract]
    void AddFacility(string facility);

}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
class FacilitiesWcfService:IFacilitiesWcfService
{
    public FacilitiesWcfService(IRepositoryWithTypedId<Facility,string> facilityRepository)
    {
        Check.Require(facilityRepository != null, "facilityRepository may not be null");

        this.facilityRepository = facilityRepository;
    }
    private readonly IRepositoryWithTypedId<Facility,string> facilityRepository;

    public void AddFacility(string facility)
    {
        facilityRepository.DbContext.BeginTransaction();

        Facility newFacility = new Facility();
        newFacility.SetAssignedIdTo(facility);
        newFacility.NAME=facility;
        newFacility.ADDRESS = facility;

        facilityRepository.DbContext.CommitTransaction();
    }
    public void Abort() { }

    public void Close() { }
}
```

And the LogisticsWCF.svc file in the web project:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Project.Wcf.FacilitiesWcfService"
 Factory="SharpArch.Wcf.NHibernate.ServiceHostFactory, SharpArch.Wcf" %>
```

I created a client with `svcutil.exe http://localhost:1905/LogisticsWCF.svc?wsdl` and then created this test case:

```
[TestFixture]
class WCFLogisticsTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CanAddFacility()
    {

        FacilitiesWcfServiceClient facility = new FacilitiesWcfServiceClient();
        facility.AddFacility("NEW");
        facility.Close();
    }
}
```

**But I get this exception:**

```
TestCase 'Tests.Project.Web.WCFLogisticsTests.CanAddFacility'
failed: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail] : The needed dependency of type FacilitiesWcfService could not be located with the ServiceLocator. You'll need to register it with the Common Service Locator (CSL) via your IoC's CSL adapter.

    Server stack trace:
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

    Exception rethrown at [0]:
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at IFacilitiesWcfService.AddFacility(String facility)
    C:\Documents and Settings\epena\My Documents\SVN\Project\tests\Project.Tests\FacilitiesWcfService.cs(58,0): at FacilitiesWcfServiceClient.AddFacility(String facility)
    WCFLogisticsTests.cs(18,0): at Tests.Project.Web.WCFLogisticsTests.CanAddFacility()


0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 4.52 seconds (NUnit 2.5.2).
```

I think I'm missing some configuration of sharp architecture, because when I don't use `Factory="SharpArch.Wcf.NHibernate.ServiceHostFactory, SharpArch.Wcf"` in the .svc file I don't get the exception, but I'm not able to write anything to the database ( I get an ISession not configured exception).

I tried to follow the Northwind example, but it's not working, What can I be missing?

Comment: Sorry thank you, i've marked the useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer, I was missing the following line in the ComponentRegistrar:

```
container.AddComponent("facilityWcfService", typeof(FacilitiesWcfService));
```

Comment: Just for anyone else who is having this problem even though they have registered their component w/the container (as in my case), step through the code where you register with the container and drill down into container.Compnents, find the component you registered, and drill down into its Status property for messages about what dependencies IT may have that can't be resolved.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very old Q&A, but I'm looking at creating a WCF service for my SharpArch MVC application. I cannot find any decent samples or guides or documentation.  You wouldn't by chance still have a small sample project for this?

Comment: Looking at the northwind example. Where is the container stuff. I roughly understand how the injections works for a asp.net mvc project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from your service method, so it needs to be marked as IsOneWay=true:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFacilitiesWcfService : ICloseableAndAbortable
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void AddFacility(string facility);

}
```

By default, WCF expects request/response, i.e. it expects to get a response back from the service method. "void" doesn't count as a response - so just mark those service methods that don't return anything with the `IsOneWay=true` and you should be fine.

Comment: Though this didn't resolve the issue, it's good to know. thank you

Comment: Feels like something WCF should be able to figure out on it's own. If it reads an attribute, why not read the return value as well? It's probably only done once on startup anyway.

Comment: @Kristoffer: yes, I agree - seems WCF could just default to IsOneWay when the return value is "void" .... oh well....